# Showing that minimal vertex deletion to a bipartite graph is NP-complete

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions

Consider the following problem whose input instance is a simple graph $G$ and a natural integer $k$.

> Is there a set $S \subseteq V(G)$ such that $G - S$ is bipartite and $|S| \leq k$?

I would like to show that this problem is $\rm{NP}$-complete by reducing either 3-SAT, $k$-CLIQUE, $k$-DOMINATING SET or $k$-VERTEX COVER to it.

I believe I can reduce the 3-COLORING problem to it so I would only need to see how to reduce one of the mentioned problems to it.  But since that would be rather messy I am wondering if someone sees an elegant reduction to the aforementioned problems.

Also, is there a name for this decision problem?

Comment: [Odd Cycle Transversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph#Odd_cycle_transversal).

Comment: This seems similar to [feedback vertex set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_vertex_set). That is, you want to find minimum subset of vertices to remove such that the resulting graph is acyclic. 
An acyclic graph is by definition a tree (or forest) which is bipartite.

Comment: @NicholasMancuso It is not so similar.  It is really as I say above, the Odd Cycle Transversal problem.  Or as Vor points out, was called the Bipartite node (or vertex) deletion by Yannakakis in the 70s and 80s.

Comment: @PålGD, I agree. I felt that the easiest reduction would be from FVS. However, that is made unnecessary by  its definition as Odd Cycle Transversal.

Comment: @Jernej: you say "... I would like to show that this problem is **in NP** by reducing it either **to** 3-SAT, the k-CLIQUE, ...". Do you mean "I would like to show that this problem is *NP-hard* using a reduction *from* 3-SAT, k-CLIQUE, ..." ? (the problem is clearly in NP because testing if a graph is bipartite can be done in linear time)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is a special case of a broader class of problems named *node-deletion problems*:

[J. M. Lewis and M. Yannakakis, "The node-deletion problem for hereditary properties is NP-complete"](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/ramsey/hered.pdf)

... This paper deals with the class of graph problems defined as follows:
for a fixed graph property $\Pi$, find the minimum number of nodes (or vertices) which must be deleted from a given graph $G$ so that the result satisfies $\Pi$. We call this the *node-deletion problem* for $\Pi$. Our results show that if $\Pi$ is a *nontrivial* property which is *hereditary* on induced subgraph, then the node-deletion problem for $\Pi$ is NP-hard. Furthermore, if we add the condition that testing for $\Pi$ can be performed in polynomial time, then our results imply that the node-deletion problem for $\Pi$ is NP-complete. ...

Your problem is the *node deletion problem for bipartiteness*, but (as noted by Pal), it is known today as the *Odd cycle traversal* (OCT) problem.

**EDIT**

For what regards a direct reduction, I thought of this one from 3SAT.

Given an instance of 3SAT with $n$ variables and $m$ clauses, build the following graph: add two nodes $x_i, \overline{x_i}$ for each variable and an edge between them. To simulate a truth assignment, add $n+1$ nodes for each variable $x_i$ and connect them both to $x_i$ and $\overline{x_i}$; in this way, in order to make a bipartite graph deleting at most $n$ nodes, at least one between $x_i$ and $\overline{x_i}$ must be deleted . Finally for each clause $C_j$ add 4 nodes and build an odd cycle that connects the variables in $C_j$.

The resulting graph $G$ can be made bipartite deleting at most $n$ nodes if and only if the original 3SAT formula is satisfiable.

[image]

Comment: This isn't really the answer the question asks for.  OP want to reduce explicitly using the given problem.  Furthermore, the problem is known today as Odd Cycle Transversal.

Comment: @PålGD: you're right.

Comment: Yeah, but I can't immediately see a reduction from OP's list of problems, though ... I only know of the one you mention, by Yannakakis.

Comment: @PålGD: I'll think about a different reduction, but to be honest I'm not sure of what exactly the OP wants (see my comment above).

Comment: @Vor What I want is to see a simple reduction to one from one of the mentioned problems. This article is known to me but I am rather looking for the most direct reduction.

Comment: @Jernej: ok, now it's clear to me. If I have some new ideas I'll expand this answer.

Comment: @Jernej: take a look at the reduction ... perhaps it is wrong, I'm still thinking about it

Comment: Vor, this reduction seems to do the trick!  Nicely done.